# /etc/tor/torrc is blank

Tags: configuration, raspberry-pi

Im following [this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi) to make by Raspberry Pi a Tor Hotspot. 
I successfully setuped a working Hotspot which is connected to internet, and now I want that all the traffic will go trough the Tor network.

In [this part of the tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/install-tor), we should install Tor using:

```
sudo apt get install tor
```

and then edit Tor configuration file using nano:

```
sudo nano /etc/tor/torrc
```

to change Tor configuration. 
I **successfuly** installed Tor, and the service is **working**, but for some reason /etc/tor/torrc exists, but it's a blank file.

How can I fix this?

Im using the latest version of Raspabian (Debian port), and Raspberry Pi model B.

Comment: Have you checked /usr/local/etc/tor/torrc ?

Comment: @mirimir Yes. But /usr/local/etc has no folder called Tor...

Comment: Well, if Tor is running, there must be a torrc somewhere? Try "find / torrc".

Comment: @mirimir **There is**, but it is empty.

Comment: I was assuming that you had created the empty file by trying to edit it. But whatever, if Tor is working, there must be a non-empty torrc somewhere.

Comment: @mirimir I tried to search for it using 'find / torrc' but it didnt find nothing. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found a solution!**

I Formatted the SD card using SDFormatter, and reburn Raspabian using Win32DiskImager - in other words, reinstalled Raspabian.

And then:

```
sudo apt-get update install tor
```

just installed tor with the full torrc file. 
I guess that it's a good solution for most of you with this problem, but because i used my Pi as a Tor Hotspot, it wasnt a big deal.